# Informatica - Writing JSON target using Data Processor

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have an Informatica Developer (IDQ) mapping that use Data Processor transformation to read from relational source (SQL server) and write an NDJSON (New Line delimited JSON) file. How ever, the output file has an extra blank line between each JSON object

### Current Output

```
{"CustInfo":{"CustName":{"FirstName":"F1","LastName":"L1"}}}

{"CustInfo":{"CustName":{"FirstName":"F1","LastName":"L1"}}}

{"CustInfo":{"CustName":{"FirstName":"F1","LastName":"L1"}}}
```

### Expected Output

```
{"CustInfo":{"CustName":{"FirstName":"F1","LastName":"L1"}}}
{"CustInfo":{"CustName":{"FirstName":"F1","LastName":"L1"}}}
{"CustInfo":{"CustName":{"FirstName":"F1","LastName":"L1"}}}
```

I tried different delimiters in the Output file properties, but none of them seems to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried NOT using a delimiter in your row? The rows should go in separate lines anyway. Give that a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

REPLACESTR (1,Output_mplt_Output,CHR(10),CHR(13), '')

Use the above expression for the port coming from Data processor. It will fix the extra line issue.